# Given the values of $abc$, $ab + ac + bc$ and $a + b + c$, how do we find the value of $a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Given the system of equations

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\hfil abc &=\;\; -6\\[6pt]
\hfil a + b + c &=\;\; \phantom{-}2\\[6pt]
\hfil ab + bc + ca &=\;\; -5
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

How do I find the value of $a^3 + b^3+ c^3$?

Comment: $(a + b + c)^3 = (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3[a^2(b+c) + b^2(a+c) + c^2(a+b)] + 6abc.$  The **trick** comes from re-expressing the $(18)$ middle terms as $$\{3 \times (a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\} - 3(a^3 +b^3 + c^3).$$ ...see next comment

Comment: This reduces the problem to determining $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2).$  Here, consider the expression $(a + b + c)^2$, and use the premises to deduce the value of $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2).$

Comment: Using two known identities for small exponents:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = (a+b+c)^2 - 2(ab+bc+ca) = 4 - 2 \cdot (-5) = 14$$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca ) + 3abc = \dots$$

Comment: Cube and muck:  $(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^2 + 3(ab^2 + ac^2+ ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2+cb^2) + 6abc$ . We need to get $ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2+bc^2+ca^2+cb^2$ to look nice in terms $ab+bc+ca$.  So get rid of the nasty squares by factoring. $ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 +cb^2 = b(ab + bc)+ c(ac + bc) + a(ab+ac)$. And to make those look right we add the extra term $b(ab + bc)+ c(ac + bc) + a(ab+ac)=b(ab+bc+ac)+c(ac+bc+ab)+a(ab+ac+bc)-3abc=(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$. So $(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-3abc$ so $2^3=(a^3+b^3+c^2)+3\cdot 2\cdot (-5)-3\cdot(-6)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984608/25554 solves a very similar problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Vieta's formulas, the roots of the following polynomial
\begin{align*}
p(x) = x^{3} - 2x^{2} - 5x + 6 
\end{align*}
are given by $a$, $b$ and $c$. Then we have that:
\begin{align*}
a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} & = (2a^{2} + 5a - 6) + (2b^{2} + 5b - 6) + (2c^{2} + 5c - 6)\\\\
& = 2(a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}) + 5(a + b + c) - 18\\\\
& = 2[(a + b + c)^{2} - 2(ab + ac + bc)] + 5(a + b + c) - 18\\\\
& = 2(4 + 2\times 5) + 5\times 2 - 18 = 20
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

A more cumbersome method:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) $$$$a^3+b^3+c^3=2 \cdot(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3\times (-6)$$$$= 2 \cdot((a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca))-18$$$$=2\cdot(4-3(-5))-18=20.$$